# im trying to transfer the elements in the list to another list. and im asking how many numbers would be transferred to the list b but error is showing

Tags: python

im trying to transfer element from list a to list b and im asking how many numbers would i like to transfer.It shows me this error:

> '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

ps. my work is not yet finished

```
a = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
b = []
transfer = int(input("how many numbers would you like to transfer:?"))
for i in a:
    if transfer == 1: 
        b.append(i) <= 2
print(b)
```

#### im expecting that number 2 will be transferred at the b list

Comment: What should the line `b.append(i) <= 2` do? Why are you running a comparison, but not checking for the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.append(i)` returns `None`. therefore the comparison `b.append(i) <= 2` raises an error. if you wanted to base your code on the length of the list you could use `len(b)`. something like:

```
for i in a:
    if len(b) < transfer:
        b.append(i)
    else:
        break
```

alternatively you could do this:

```
b = a[:transfer]
```

this would just use the [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of the old list `a` as the new list `b`.

Comment: It would probably be better to use `enumerate` instead of recalculation length of `b` every iteration.

Comment: @OlvinRoght sure, but the slice version is so much better that i did not feel the need to improve that any further.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First of all** you should prevent error when you convert input to int. There are 2 ways how to do this.

   1. **Try .. except** statement.

      ```
      transfer = -1
      while transfer < 0:
          try:
              inp = input("how many numbers would you like to transfer:?")
              transfer = int(inp)
          except:
              print("Invalid input.")
      ```
   2. [`isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal).

      ```
      transfer = -1
      while transfer < 0:
          inp = input("how many numbers would you like to transfer:?")
          if inp.isdecimal():
              transfer = int(inp)
          else:
              print("Invalid input.")
      ```
2. Now about main task. There's 3 methods how to solve it.

   1. For loop using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

      ```
      for i, el in enumerate(a):
          if i < transfer:
              b.append(el)
          else:
              break
      ```
   2. List comprehension:

      ```
      b = [el for i, el in enumerate(a) if i < transfer]
      ```
   3. List slicing:

      ```
      b = a[:transfer]
      ```