# Validating if variable is int

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script to create vlan in cisco switches, and I need the user to input a number to the script.

I'm having trouble to make the script validate if the input is a number(must be int) and if the number is inside the range 2~4094, before it moves to the next steps.

I already wrote the rest of the script.

Comment: Try `str.isdigit()`. For example, `"1".isdigit()` returns `True` and `"1.1".isdigit()` returns `False`, then you can check its range.

Comment: @TianboJi, `isdigit("½")` will return `True`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght  What is your Python version? I tested `"½".isdigit()` on Python 3.7.3 and 2.7.10, both return `False`.

Comment: @TianboJi, sorry, this example is for `isnumeric()`. `'³'.isdigit()` this will return True for both python versions. The idea is for validation before type cast to int `isdecimal()` should be used.

Comment: @OlvinRoght you are correct, `'³'.isdigit()` does return `True`. `isdecimal()` is a better solution for this question.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
def validate(num):
    try:
        n = int(num)
        return 2 <= n <= 4094
    except:
        return False
```

The above function returns `True` if the number is an integer in the specified range, `False` otherwise.

Comment: thanks... but when I try you example... if the user input something like TESTE besides an int, the scripts goes on.

Comment: We'd need to know how you're calling your script, and how you're using my function. You need to provide a lot more details for people to be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    val = int(user_input)
    print("user input is an int")
except ValueError:
    print("user_input is not an int")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal) to check if string contains only digits.

```
inp = input("Enter number: ")
if inp.isdecimal():
    n = int(inp)
else:
    print("Not a number")
```

If you need function:

```
def validate(inp):
    return isinstance(inp, str) and inp.isdecimal()


inp = input("Enter number: ")
print(validate(inp))
```

Answer (score 0):

When the function below return True, you can do the Math you need to do with the number.

```
def as_int_in_range(value,range):
    try:
        value = int(value)
        if value >= range[0] and value <= range[1]:
            return True,value 
        else:
            return False,None 
    except ValueError:
        return False,None

is_int,val = as_int_in_range('12',(10,100))
if is_int:
    # do something with 'val' assuming it is int in the range
else:
    # do something  else
```

Comment: thank you... but if the input is not a int, I need the script to ask again for the value, until the provided input is a int

Comment: @Douglas, apply `while` loop. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256888/10824407) answer, I've provided some examples there.